# Write Array to a file ArchiveRootObject

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nskeyedarchiver

```
    NSMutableArray *esami = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    //make a file name to write the data to using the
    //documents directory:
    NSString *fullFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/new", documentsDirectory];
    esami = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:fullFileName];
    Esame *add=[[Esame alloc]initWithNome:materia voto:voto crediti:crediti anno:anno];
    [esami addObject:add];
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:esami toFile:fullFileName];
```

I can't understad why this code doesn't work..
If I use a file already written in my root directory I can add the new element to my array and write it but if I use another file (new in this case) it doesn't work.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. It should be `NSString *fullFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"new"];`

Comment: It's ok but it doesn't change anything!

Comment: I know, that's why I didn't add this as an asnwer but as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but I resolved this issue with this code

```
NSMutableArray *esami = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:fullFileName];

if(esami.count==0){
    NSMutableArray *esamiNew=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [esamiNew addObject:[[Esame alloc]initWithNome:materia voto:voto crediti:crediti anno:anno]];

    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:esamiNew toFile:fullFileName];

}
else{

    [esami addObject:[[Esame alloc]initWithNome:materia voto:voto crediti:crediti anno:anno]];
    NSLog(@"num %d",esami.count);
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:esami toFile:fullFileName];

}
```

Does is it a bug??